# Is it possible to detect that Watch is paired with iPhone or not without having Watch target

Tags: ios, xcode, watchkit, apple-watch, watchconnectivity

I am working on project, where we have only iOS target and there is no watch application or extension as part of project. But we need to detect that Apple watch is paired or not with iPhone ?
I have tried using below code but is always return false.

```
WCSession.default.isPaired
```